# How to lint a yaml and ignore multiple "depends_on"?

Tags: yaml, lint

I wrote a script that creates a local development environment using a docker-compose.yml file.

When running the script, I want to use a yaml linter command to validate that the file is a valid yaml before upping the environment and to do that I'm using the command yamllint.

In this docker-compose.yml file, there is more than one service which "depeneds_on" another service but when I run yamllint, it returns the following error:

```
47:5      error    duplication of key "depends_on" in mapping  (key-duplicates)
```

Which is not a real error, but since the lint is part of the script run then I cannot count on its exit code as it counts this error as an error while in reality, it's not.

An example portion of the docker-compose.yml file:

```
  microservice-one:
    image: ms-one:feature-local_development_env
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: 'development'
      NPM_TOKEN: 'SECRET'
    ports:
      - "3013:3000"
    depends_on:
      - redis-cluster
  microservice-two:
    image: ms-two:feature-local_development_env
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: 'development'
      NPM_TOKEN: 'SECRET'
    ports:
      - "3014:3000"
    depends_on:
      - redis-cluster
networks:
  default:
```

Is there any other command line yaml linter that you know which will not count more than one "depends_on" as an error?

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer and thought I'll share it with whoever gets here.

So the solution is to override yamllint's default configuration by creating a specific yamllint configuration file.

In my case, the file looks like so:

```
extends: default

rules:
  key-duplicates: disable
```

Then, I'm running the command like so:

```
yamllint -d config_file docker-compose.yml
```

More options can be found in [yamllint's official documentation page](https://yamllint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/configuration.html),

Answer (score 0):

If you need only syntax error and nothing else , below command can be used.

```
yamllint -d "{rules:{}}"
```